# MSAL: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (login.microsoftonline.com:7002)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using this piece of code from the MSAL library.

---

Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (login.microsoftonline.com:7002)
But I never specified login.microsoft as an Authority endpoint. I'm using my own oauth server onpremises.

```
static private string authorityUri = "https://myownserver:7002/cas/oauth2/token";

static async Task<string> GetBearerAccessToken(string instanceUri)
{
    IConfidentialClientApplication ica = 
    ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
       .WithCertificate(GetCertificateByPFXFile(pfxFile, pass))
       .WithAuthority(authorityUri)
       .Build();
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await ica
       .AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { $"{environmentUri}/.default" })
       .ExecuteAsync();

    return authResult.AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: You are creating a proxy.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/144836/using-msal-msgraph-behind-a-reverse-proxy?force_isolation=true